# Argparse and unittest.main()

Tags: python, argparse, python-unittest

I just added a graph utility to a unittest -- basically, the fully automatic version of the test just does a numerical compare, but I want a human to be able to ask for plots.

Just using argparse, `unittest.main()` was choking if I used my new argument.  What I'm currently doing is checking for that argument, then deleting it from `sys.argv` which just seems *wrong*.

Is there a better way to skin this cat?

- A way to tell argparse to consume arguments from sys.argv.  Probably still wrong, but it's not me doing it, so it's OK.
- A way to tell argparse to cough up version of sys.argv with all the "used arguments" taken out -- this would be cool, because it looks like `unittest.main()` will take an alternate argv.
- A way to tell `unittest.main()` to ignore arguments.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description='Test correction'
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        '--plot-results',
        help='Plot results of cal test',
        action='store_true'
    )
    args = parser.parse_args()

    if args.plot_results:
        while '--plot-results' in sys.argv:
            sys.argv.remove('--plot-results')

    unittest.main()
```

Comment: You'll want to use a `TestLoader` + `TestRunner`.  The [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#loading-and-running-tests) show a couple of examples.

Comment: I'd probably tackle this by copying `unittest.main()` to the local code base, importing its depdencies and calling them directly rather than going through the original function. Once that works, you can find argparse (or its equivalent) in that function and insert your argument there.

Comment: @SarahMesser That's not at all necessary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Argument.parse_known_args` is basically your second option: parse the arguments you define, and get back the ones you don't recognize to pass on to `unittest.main`.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description='Test correction'
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        '--plot-results',
        help='Plot results of cal test',
        action='store_true'
    )
    args, remaining = parser.parse_known_args()

    # Restore the script name which parse_known_args() also stripped.
    remaining.insert(0, sys.argv[0])
    unittest.main(argv=remaining)
```

Probably goes without saying, but don't add any arguments to `parser` that conflict with the parsers used by `unittest` itself. These are (mostly?) documented [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#command-line-options).

Comment: Roger on not stomping on existing `unittest` arguments.